# Require custom checkout field from extension

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I am using a zipcode(postcode) check extension that adds a custom zipcode and house number field. Now I want those to be required so they have to be filled in before going to the  next step.

Currently when going to the next step it does say **'This is a required field'**. But it still goes to the next step. Any idea what i'm missing?

**postcodenl.html**

```
<form class="form form-postcodenl"
      data-bind="attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-postcodenl'}">
    <fieldset class="fieldset"
              data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading, visible: isVisible(), attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-fieldset'}">

        <h3>Adresvalidatie</h3>

        <!-- ko if: element.messageText -->
        <span translate="element.messageText" class="information"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="field required postcode-check">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="text"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: postcodeNL,
                            attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-postcode'}"
                       name="postcodenl_postcode"
                       data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-postcode'}">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Postcode'"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required postcode-check">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="text"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: houseNumber,
                            attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-house'}"
                       name="postcodenl_house_number"
                       data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-house'}">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'HouseNumber'"></span>
                </label>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required postcode-check housenumber" data-bind="visible: houseAdditionalOptions().length > 0">
            <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-addition'}">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'HouseNumber Addition'"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select class="admin__control-select"
                        name="postcodenl_house_addition"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        data-bind="
                        attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-postcodenl-addition'},
                        options: houseAdditionalOptions,
                        value: houseAddition,
                        optionsValue: 'value',
                        optionsText: 'label'"
                />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input class="input-text" type="hidden" name="street[0]"/>
        <input class="input-text" type="hidden" name="street[1]"/>
        <input class="input-text" type="hidden" name="postcode"/>

        <address class="autocomplete-result" data-bind="attr: {'id': element.addressType + '-nl-result'}"></address>

        <div role="alert" class="message warning"
             data-bind="visible: (validationMessage() && validationMessage().length > 0)" generated="true">
            <span data-bind="text: validationMessage()"/>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

It's about the postcode and huisnummer field.

Comment: custom zipcode and house number field is already set required field

Comment: yeah but i'm still able to click on the next button and it goes to the next step :(

Comment: place order botton not active or not?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192403/custom-added-field-to-checkout-is-not-validating-when-i-go-the-next-step

please refer to this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a validation to the shipping.js file from the magento checkout.

```
validatePostcodeCheck: function () {
    if (window.checkoutConfig.shipping.modules.hoofdfabriek_postcodenl_enable) {
        if ($('#shipping-postcodenl-postcode').val().length === 0 || $('#shipping-postcodenl-house').val().length === 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
},
```

It also checks if the zipcode extension is turned on by checking the window variable.